# run.sh not found during push to heroku for no reason

Tags: docker, heroku, sh

Once I've done with Django application I created pull request and merged 2 branches, pushed and released the container to Heroku but for no reason an error occured:

```
2021-10-01T15:54:44.673598+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-10-01T15:54:50.776869+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `run.sh`
2021-10-01T15:54:51.721903+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2021-10-01T15:54:51.834182+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-10-01T15:54:51.580990+00:00 app[web.1]: /bin/sh: run.sh: not found
```

In latest commits there were no changes in Dockerfile or in `run.sh`, no paths were changed either.
`run.sh` is located in `scripts/run.sh`

`run.sh:`

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

npm run prod
npm prune --production
python manage.py wait_for_db
python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate

gunicorn placerem.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:$PORT
```

`Dockerfile:`

```
FROM python:3.9-alpine3.13

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt
COPY ./placerem /placerem
COPY ./scripts /scripts

WORKDIR /placerem

RUN apk add --update --no-cache nodejs npm && \
    npm ci

RUN python -m venv /py && \
    /py/bin/pip install --upgrade pip && \
    apk add --update --no-cache postgresql-client && \
    apk add --update --no-cache --virtual .tmp-deps \
        build-base jpeg-dev postgresql-dev musl-dev linux-headers \
        zlib-dev libffi-dev openssl-dev python3-dev cargo && \
    apk add --update --no-cache libjpeg && \
    /py/bin/pip install -r /requirements.txt && \
    apk del .tmp-deps && \
    adduser --disabled-password --no-create-home placerem && \
    mkdir -p /vol/web/static && \
    mkdir -p /vol/web/media && \
    chown -R placerem:placerem /vol && \
    chown -R placerem:placerem /py/lib/python3.9/site-packages/social_django/migrations && \
    chown -R placerem:placerem /py/lib/python3.9/site-packages/easy_thumbnails/migrations && \
    chown -R placerem:placerem package.json && \
    chmod -R +x /scripts

ENV PATH="/scripts:/py/bin:$PATH"

USER placerem

CMD ["run.sh"]
```

I tried to rename file, copy it to another folder, but nothing worked. The only way I found was to  roll back but that makes no sense. How to fix it?

Comment: What /did/ change in the intermediate commits? My first guess is that one of the commands before `chmod -R +x /scripts` is failing.

Comment: @walter, I don't think it depends on commits, because I've tested previous builds (from previous commits) and even then nothing worked.

Comment: You said when you rolled back it worked, so what happened between it working and it not working?

Comment: @walter If I roll back via heroku, to previous deployed build, it'll work as intended. But if I revert an older commit via GitHub and push it to heroku it'll throw this error.
Before redeploying I merged 2 branches without any issues. After it an error occured.